# Rust impl Iterator for Range<T> on custom type

Tags: loops, rust, iterator

I have a point struct, like so:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
struct Point {
  x: i32,
  y: i32,
}
```

I would like to iterate between points like so:

```rust
let start = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };
let end = Point { x: 3, y: 3 };
for p in start..end {
  // p should be
  // (0, 0)
  // (1, 0)
  // (2, 0)
  // (0, 1)
  // (1, 1)
  // (2, 1)
  // (0, 2)
  // etc
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10296b16a3361f9097e331f84011fded).

However, I cannot seem to implement this. `start..end` produces a `Range<Pos>`, which is a type in the standard library. So I cannot make a custom `impl Iterator for Range<Pos>`, as none of those types are in the current crate.

I also cannot `impl Step for Point`, as the iterator must know the start and end of the range. `Step` does not give you this information.

Lastly, I cannot write a wrapper for `Iterator`, as `impl MyIterator for Range<Point>` will fail with an error saying that `Step` is not implemented for `Point`.

Is there any way to solve this? My current solution is to define a `to` function on a `Point`, so that you can write this:

```rust
for p in start.to(end) {
  // works as expected
}
```

The `to` function produces a custom iterator which does what I'm looking for. However, I still would like to use the `..` syntax.

EDIT: AFAIK, [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42168#issuecomment-873306130) is what is needed for this to work. Based on these comments, this looks impossible.

Comment: It does seem the syntax you want is impossible. However, my two cents is that `start..end` is ambiguous anyways and would suggest a named function like `grid_points()` or something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do this directly, as you've discovered. However I wouldn't get too hung up on the syntax, as `point..point` doesn't necessarily make the code more readable. In fact it hides information about the ordering and makes it more difficult to later add an iterator that goes in column order instead of rows.

A design that communicates the order, while still using the range syntax could be:

```rust
fn row_major(range: Range<Point>) -> impl Iterator<Item = Point> {
    (range.start.y..range.end.y)
        .flat_map(move |y| (range.start.x..range.end.x).map(move |x| Point { x, y }))
}

fn main() {
    let start = Point { x: 0, y: 0 };
    let end = Point { x: 2, y: 2 };
    let result: Vec<_> = row_major(start..end).collect();

    assert_eq!(
        result,
        vec![
            Point { x: 0, y: 0 },
            Point { x: 1, y: 0 },
            Point { x: 0, y: 1 },
            Point { x: 1, y: 1 },
        ]
    )
}
```

`row_major` may not be the best name, depending on your application. Other options are things like `horizontal_iter`, `hrange` or `iter_rows`. Giving it a name like that makes it clear to a reader what order to expect and also gives the opportunity to add a symmetric column-major (vertical) version of the function later.

You could also extend this to support `..end` and `start..=end` variants for more expressivity, while excluding `start..` which doesn't make sense here.